High Rate of Critical Errors in Event Viewer under AsyncCausality - Impact on Gaming Performance
I've encountered a significant issue with Event Viewer on multiple PCs in my household, specifically under the path: Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > AsyncCausality. The Event Viewer logs critical errors at an alarmingly high rate, nearly 100 per second, with several specific event IDs repeatedly occurring:
Critical 8208: Event fired when an asynchronous operation is completed.
Critical 16400: Event fired when a synchronous work item starts.
Critical 20496: Event fired when a synchronous work item completes.
Critical 4112: Event fired when an asynchronous operation is created.
The Details pane often lists PIDs associated with TextInputHost.exe, gamingservices.exe, and occasionally Token Broker. I identified them with Process Explorer.
This phenomenon is consistent on at least two PCs in my home, leading me to suspect a potential environmental factor at play. Interestingly, every PC in my household experiences frametime spikes during online gaming, and I'm beginning to wonder if these performance issues could be related to the excessive logging observed in the Event Viewer.
Could this high frequency of logged events be normal under any circumstances, or is it indicative of a deeper underlying problem? More importantly, could there be a correlation between these Event Viewer logs and the gaming performance issues?
(https://i.sstatic.net/RjXib.png)
I cannot find any information on the errors online.
